# Dynamically changing a Smarty variable via. PHP?

Tags: php, variables, dynamic, smarty, smarty3

I have an outer template in Smarty (the background template), which displays the versioning number of a certain section of the project in the footer.

The variable in question, `{$NoVersion}`, is a string parameter returned from a web-service response. I now have two seperate web-service calls, each one being for a different section of the project and containing a different string parameter. I would like to change the versioning string in the footer depending on the section of the project I am on.

I can assign one of these using PHP when the page itself loads, but I'm finding it impossible to modify a template dynamically after a click/load of a separate page has occurred..

So, how can you dynamically modify a smarty variable in a defined template inside PHP?

My code is below.

**zone.tpl:**

```
<div>
    <p>The version - {$NoVersion}</p>
</div>
```

**Php:**

```
$wsName = $this->nameWS; // this returns a string - either 'reporting' or 'other' depending on which section of the website has been selected.

if($wsName == "reporting"){ // reporting is one of the two sections
   $tplContent = new CopixTpl(); // template content
   $modEvadmin = new boxModule('evadmin'); // new module
   boxWebServices::create($wsName);  // start web service dependant on section
   $RetourDTOD = boxWebServices::call($wsName.'|GetVersion'); // get string parameter
   $tplContent->assign('NoVersion', (is_string($RetourDTOD)) ? $RetourDTOD : '?'); // Is supposed to assign string parameter to {$NoVersion} smarty variable in zone.tpl.         
}
```

Am I missing something? I seem to be returning the strings and everything, but the last line does not update the smarty variable on the page in front of me. Do I have to signify a specific template file in there somewhere?

---

Here's some var_dumps of above:

**$wsName var_dump** = `string(9) "reporting"`

**$tplContent var_dump before assignment** =

```
object(CopixTpl)#350 (2) {
  ["_vars"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["templateFile"]=>
  NULL
}
```

**$RetourDTOD  var_dump** = `string(14) "1.0.8"`

**$tplContent var_dump after assignment (last line of code above)** =

```
object(CopixTpl)#350 (2) {
  ["_vars"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["evaNoVersion"]=>
    string(14) "1.0.8"
  }
  ["templateFile"]=>
  NULL
}
```

---

If the above is confusing, basically do this:

> If section:
>       1. Get string variable from webservice.
>       2. Get particular template file.
>       3. Overwrite the current Smarty variable value in that template with my new string variable.

Comment: "I'm finding it impossible to modify a template dynamically after a click/load of a separate page has occurred"  What does this mean?  You clearly know that PHP is running server side and you cannot modify a page after it has been sent to the client...  What exactly are you trying to do?  If you want to change the value, just assign a new value.

Comment: @Brad Yes, but each time I click the section, this function is called - I would like to check which section of the website the user is (which I'm doing above), and modify the smarty variable and re-send the template. I can't seem to actually access/modify the smarty variable at all here..

Comment: where do you put the smarty display() order, before or after that piece of PHP?

Comment: @user2369736, You're confusing me with this user clicking section nonsense.  Let's simplify this a bit.  A client requests a page.  You want to do what exactly?  You are already assigning data to that template, just assign the value you want.

Comment: @Brad I want to check `$this->nameWS`, which I do above, and depending on one of two strings returned, change the NoVersion smarty variable inside `zone.tpl` appropriately. I assumed my last line does give `NoVersion` the string value, but nothing seems to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$tplContent` object presumably represents a template, or the variables to prepare one (it doesn't appear to actually be descended from a Smarty object), but nowhere in the code you've pasted do you show where you actually render that template into HTML.

Just creating a new object of the right type won't change what the existing rendering code does - you need to make your assignment on the object which is actually used to display the page.

Comment: That's it - I can't seem to find smarty documentation showing how I can access a particular template and modify the variable on that template though

Comment: @user2369736 Smarty is a rendering engine: you give it a template file and a set of variables, and it renders some HTML (or whatever is in the template). There is no central registry which knows what templates are about to be used, you have to find the code that uses them.